# ADO.Net Excel, Checking if a table exists?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, excel, ado.net

I'm using ADO.Net to work with an Excel Document.  Essentially, I'm looking up values in a table called "source" and creating a new table called "result" which will be populated with the results of my query.

I have a couple of questions..

- A) How can I check if a table exists
  and create a new one if it doesn't?
- B) Is a table the same as a sheet in
  Excel?

I'm working from this example..
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934#10

Answer (score 1):

Here's my best solution as of now..

```
dt = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, "TABLE"})

If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            If row(column).ToString() = "result" Then
                blnResultTableExists = True
            End If
        Next
    Next
End If
```